# add a key value pair to hash in first array depending on the substring from second array

Tags: ruby

I have an array with hashes and another array with strings. I'd like to add a key value pair to hash in first array depending on the substring from second array:

given:

```
export_configs = [
  {"foo"=>[{"state"=>"a"}, {"format"=>"aa"}, {"time"=>120}]}, 
  {"bar"=>[{"state"=>"b"}, {"format"=>"bb"}, {"time"=>30}]}, 
  {"baz"=>[{"state"=>"c"}, {"format"=>"cc"}, {"time"=>5}]}
]

topics = [
  "downloads/foo/7s699GToRzf9ViqGU5js/export", "downloads/bar/o679WbgrcNAJepprCWzR/export", "downloads/baz/_s5HQWr1xxq5yB7zPPhQ/export"
]
```

goal: to add a new key "url" with value from @topics depending of the substring of the hash-key eg. "downloads/foo/" or ".../bar/..." So that it looks like this:

Result:

```
export_configs = [
  {"foo"=>[{"state"=>"a"}, {"format"=>"aa"}, {"time"=>120}, {"url"=>"downloads/foo/7s699GToRzf9ViqGU5js/export"}]}, 
  {"bar"=>[{"state"=>"b"}, {"format"=>"bb"}, {"time"=>30}, {"url"=>"downloads/bar/o679WbgrcNAJepprCWzR/export"}]}, 
  {"baz"=>[{"state"=>"c"}, {"format"=>"cc"}, {"time"=>5}, {"url"=>"downloads/baz/_s5HQWr1xxq5yB7zPPhQ/export"}]}
]
```

my attempt:

```
export_configs.map do |topic|
  topics.each do |t| 
    t.include? topic.first.keys[0]
    topic.merge("url" => t) 
  end
end
```

But I get the error:

````
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<Array:0x0000000001cbe8b8>```
````

Comment: do you want to modify the `export_configs` array in-place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I get the error

This is because you do `topic.first.keys` instead of `topic.keys.first`; the difference is that `topic.first` behaves like `topic.to_a.first`, and `Hash#to_a` returns an array of key/value pairs, e.g. `[[k1, v1], [k2, v2], ...]`.

The below solution goes the other way around; it iterates over `export_configs`, and then tries to find the corresponding topic. In your example, each `export_config` hash comprises one key/value pair, but I don't see a reason why there can't be more, so this code does another loop inside.

It also makes use of `Enumerable#find` to get an object out of an array that matches a certain predicate; this is useful for your problem in particular, despite it not being the fastest.

```rb
export_configs.map do |config|
  # defensive: there could be more keys in config
  config.map do |key, values|
    # this operation scans topics each time, not very fast
    topic = topics.find { |url| url.include? key }
    # make a copy here, so that original variable isn't modified
    values = values + [{ 'url' => topic }] if topic
    [key, values]
  end.to_h
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export_configs.each do |topic|
  topics.each do |t|
    topic.merge!({'url' => t}) if t.include? topic.keys[0]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because `topic.first` is an Array. This is because you are calling [Enumerable#first](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) Hash (which returns an Array, even if not documented, for what I ca see). check it out:

```
export_configs.each do |topic|
  topics.each do |t|
    p topic 
    p topic.first
    p topic.keys.first # <-- this is the guy, see next
  end
end
```

You can get your result pushing to the Array, not merging to an Hash (this changes the `export_configs` content:

```
export_configs.each do |topic|
  topics.each do |t|
    key = topic.keys.first
    if t.include? key
      topic[key] << {'url' => t}
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Other option**

I'd map the urls to a hash, just to be sure there are no "foo", "bar", "baz" elsewhere in the url (changes the `export_configs` content):

```
topics_h = topics.map { |url| [url.split('/')[1], url] }.to_h
#=> {"foo"=>"downloads/foo/7s699GToRzf9ViqGU5js/export",
#=>  "bar"=>"downloads/bar/o679WbgrcNAJepprCWzR/export",
#=>  "baz"=>"downloads/baz/_s5HQWr1xxq5yB7zPPhQ/export"}
```

Then loop through the new hash:

```
topics_h.each do |k, v|
  export_configs.each do |h|
    h[k] << {'url' => v} if h.key? k
  end
end

#=> [{"foo"=>[{"state"=>"a"}, {"format"=>"aa"}, {"time"=>120},{"url"=>"downloads/foo/7s699GToRzf9ViqGU5js/export"}]},
#=>  {"bar"=>[{"state"=>"b"}, {"format"=>"bb"}, {"time"=>30}, {"url"=>"downloads/bar/o679WbgrcNAJepprCWzR/export"}]},
#=>  {"baz"=>[{"state"=>"c"}, {"format"=>"cc"}, {"time"=>5},  {"url"=>"downloads/baz/_s5HQWr1xxq5yB7zPPhQ/export"}]}]
```

Comment: `Enumerable#first` returns an array, because it calls `Hash#to_a`, which returns an array of key/value pairs.